# Updating SwiftUI navigation bar title

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have a `Form` view that sets the navigation bar title to "Settings" and a `Picker` view inside the `Form` view that sets the navigation bar title to "Options".

When navigating to `Picker` view, the navigation bar title does not get set to "Options", but the back button text does. Also, when navigating back to `Form` view, the navigation bar title is changed to "Options".

How can I have the navigation bar title be "Settings" while on `Form` view and "Options" while on `Picker` view? Thanks!

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Picker(selection: $currentSelection, label: Text("Options")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< options.count) {
                    Text(options[$0])
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Options", displayMode: .inline)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put navigation title modifier inside `Picker`. Also as same Text view from `Picker` item is used to present selection in `Form` we need to make Options title conditional.

Here is a demo of approach. Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

```
Form {
    Picker(selection: $currentSelection, label: Text("Options")) {
        ForEach(0 ..< options.count) {
            if $0 != currentSelection {
               Text(options[$0])
                .navigationBarTitle("Options", displayMode: .inline)
            } else {
               Text(options[$0])
            }
        }
    }
}
.navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
```